# Animate Object circle path and light

Tags: animation

I have a basic saucer shaped (UFO) Identified Flying object with a circle path matching the outside diameter of the saucer. I have a light constrained to the circle path and the light rotates around the circle and the rim of the saucer.
I want to animate the saucer and keep the light rotating around the saucer.
Every time I move the saucer the origin changes and the light no longer rotates around the saucer.  How can I animate the saucer and keep the light rotating around it.?

I thought I had it working by parenting the light to the circle and then the circle to the saucer. I saved and closed Blender when I thought I had it working and when I reopened the project it no longer worked. I'm an old f**t so I could be wrong that I had it working, but I thought I had it working. LOL

I'm not new to Blender, but I am fairly (little more than a noob) new animating.
Any help here is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Grey Wolf, and welcome . Since you've described what is, at first sight, a correct method, it's hard to diagnose without further information. Please share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , so we can hunt down your problem.

Comment: @Robin Betts
Thank you, I will upload the file ASAP.

Comment: @Robin Betts file uploaded.

Comment: If [this is a fix](https://blend-exchange.com/b/MQgmoD54/) then the only problem was that the Bézier Circle was not ( Ctrl-P ) parented to the ship. The Point light is already constrained to the Circle, it doesn't need parenting too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I gave it a try but I get the same result. Also, when parenting the circle to the (Spaceship) object, the circle snaps completely outside of the object, It stays on the same Z axis but moves about 2 grid spaces away. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you downloaded the .blend linked in my last comment?